# Android sql database

Tags: java, android, sql, database, eclipse

I try to connect from eclipse emulator android to an sql server using this code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://83.212.240.15:1521/hua;encrypt=false;user=xxxxxx;password=xxx;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
String username = "xxxxx";
String password = "xxxxx";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("insert into picture values('hi');");
conn.close();
```

but in the database nothing happens.Any ideas?

Thanks in adnvanced

Comment: Check your spelling for `String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://83.212.240.15:1521/hua;encrypt=false;user=xxxxxx;password=xxx;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";` You mispelled FALSE

Comment: Still nothing happens

Answer (score 4):

Well this is not directly the answer you are expecting but I would not suggest to access a database directly. Better use e.g. a REST webservice for all database access. So you don't need to make your credentials public.

It is quiet simple so observe the network traffic so it would be realy easy to hack you database server(s).

Anyway if your App is really only for private usage you need to check that you app has the Internet permission for accessing your network ressources.

Comment: Yes it has the persmission.

Comment: Which exceptions do you get exactly? Can you provide a stacktrace from the logcat?

Comment: I don't have any excetpions the program runs well